# How to call IElasticClient.Index() when the type that we are indexing is generic

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When I have an explicitly typed object, I have no problems indexing.  For example,

```
EventObject e;
IElasticClient client;
client.Index(e); // perfectly valid
```

However, I have a class where the type is generic.  This is my class

```
class FantasticClass<INDEXCLASS>
{
    IElasticClient client;
    public FantasticClass(IElasticClient c)
    {
        client = c;
    }

    public INDEXCLASS Add(INDEXCLASS entity)
    {
        client.Index(entity); // can't compile!
        // or
        client.Index<INDEXCLASS>(entity); // can't compile!
    }
}
```

How do you index with Nest when the class type is inferred?

Comment: What is difference between `es` and `c`?

Comment: @Rob Sorry, that was a typo when moving between machines.  `es` == `client`.  I will fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with it not compiling are due to the class missing the declaration of what type `INDEXCLASS` is this should resolve that error:

```
class FantasticClass<INDEXCLASS> where INDEXCLASS : class
```

Also the `Add` method has a return type of INDEXCLASS however nothing is returning in the method. Either change it to `void` or return the `entity` variable after it has been indexed.